# optparse NA default not being overwritten by command-line argument

Tags: r, command-line-arguments

Consider the following script:

```
library(optparse)

option_list <- list(
    make_option(c('--sample_p'), default=NA, dest='sample_p', help='Sample probability of inclusion if randomly sampling records')
)

args <- parse_args(OptionParser(option_list=option_list))
print(args)

if(!is.na(args$sample_p)){
    print('Chose to sample')
}else{
    print('Did not choose to sample')
}
```

I want to pass a floating-point value to the script, to be stored in `args$sample_p`. I've tried the following, but neither approach leaves me with `0.05` being stored:

```sh
$ Rscript test.R --sample_p 0.05
$sample_p
[1] NA

$help
[1] FALSE

[1] "Did not choose to sample"
$ Rscript test.R --sample_p=0.05
Warning message:
In getopt(spec = spec, opt = args) :
  long flag sample_p given a bad argument
$sample_p
[1] NA

$help
[1] FALSE

[1] "Did not choose to sample"
```

However, if I change the default value of `sample_p` to a number, instead of `NA`, it works:

```
library(optparse)

option_list <- list(
    make_option(c('--sample_p'), default=0, dest='sample_p', help='Sample probability of inclusion if randomly sampling records')
)

args <- parse_args(OptionParser(option_list=option_list))
print(args)

if(!is.na(args$sample_p)){
    print('Chose to sample')
}else{
    print('Did not choose to sample')
}
```

```sh
$ Rscript test.R --sample_p 0.05
$sample_p
[1] 0.05

$help
[1] FALSE

[1] "Chose to sample"
```

Why does the `NA` as a default value cause problems?

Comment: Interestingly, `default=NULL` does not cause this issue, contrary to `default=NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `NA_real_` to specify the kind of NA to use in this context (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NA.html).

```
option_list <- list(
    make_option(c('--sample_p'), default=NA_real_, dest='sample_p', help='Sample probability of inclusion if randomly sampling records')
)
```

This is basically because of how `type` is handled in `make_option()`.